# How can I send part of code asynch?

Tags: javascript, .net, linq, serialization, asynchronous

In my response, I have a function that load a model-data of point (Google point) and serialize it, sending to the client when finish.

The code looks like:

```
IList<PuntoMappa> punti = new List<PuntoMappa>();
foreach (Ricettivito Struttura in StruttureFinali)
{
    PuntoMappa punto = new PuntoMappa();
    punto.Titolo = Struttura.Titolo;
    punto.Lat = Struttura.Geo.Latitudine;
    punto.Lng = Struttura.Geo.Longitudine;
    punto.Categoria = Struttura.Categoria;
    punti.Add(punto);
    }
}

m_strPunti = jsonSerializer.Serialize(punti);
if (m_strPunti == "")
{
    m_strPunti = "{ }";
}

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "puntiLocalizzati", "var puntiLocalizzati = " + m_strPunti + ";", true);
```

the problem is that I have 200/300 object inside `StruttureFinali`, and it took somethings like 10 seconds to load this function and serialize it.

The webpage won't show until all functions in the .cs on the WebForm is finished.

Is there a way to load this content asynch? So display the code normally, and return "this function" asynch? Client side I can manage the whole operation with ready/load events.

P.S.

`StruttureFinali` is a `List<Ricettivito>.ToList();`

Comment: Yeah but with ajax request I need a sort of load, recall, manage ajax, show

Comment: If all act in a single request would be pretty nice...

Comment: it takes you less than 20-30 lines of code to write that ajax request call server and client side combined, ok i might have exaggerated a bit but you get the point that it's not a big deal